# How can I enumerate the undefined functions in a SymPy expression?

Tags: sympy

I have a variety of SymPy expressions involving UndefinedFunction instances:

```
f = Function('f')
g = Function('g')
e = f(x) / g(x)
```

How can I obtain a list of the function invocations appearing in such expressions?  In this example, I'd like to get `[f(x), g(x)]`.

I'm aware of `free_symbols` but it kicks back `set([x])` (as it should).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that you want to use `atoms`, but be aware that all functions in SymPy subclass from `Function`, not just undefined functions. So you'll also get

```
>>> (sin(x) + f(x)).atoms(Function)
set([f(x), sin(x)])
```

So you'll want to further reduce your list to only those functions that are `UndefinedFunction`s. Note that `UndefinedFunction` is the metaclass of `f`, so do to this, you need something like

```
>>> [i for i in expr.atoms(Function) if isinstance(i.__class__, UndefinedFunction)]
[f(x)]
```

Comment: I also found `from sympy.core.function import AppliedUndef
` and that using `expr.atoms(AppliedUndef)` worked well.  Though I suppose it won't find everything that `UndefinedFunction` would since the latter would find non-invocations.  Thank you.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Using `AppliedUndef` is much easier than what I said.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the `atoms` member method can accept a type on which to filter.  So

```
e.atoms(Function)
```

returns

```
set([f(x), g(x)])
```

as I'd wanted.  And that fancier things like

```
e.diff(x).atoms(Derivative)
```

are possible.